# Pass failed cards to next day in Anki

Tags: python, anki

I'm looking for the python line to pass a failed card to the next day.

Suppose that we were studying a deck of 3 cards. I failed 2 cards, succeeded 1 only. When I want to restudy the failed cards after the first review, I stop my revision so that I can launch my addon to pass directly my failed cards as succeeded to finish my deck for today. Then tomorrow I will see my 2 cards I failed the day before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution ! Here it is:

```
import time

card = mw.col.getCard(1588339124244)
print(card)
card.timerStarted = time.time() # Start a timer otherwise it won't work
mw.col.sched.answerCard(card, 2)
```